# How to install pinned dependencies using wheels from pypi?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, python-wheel

I have a package with a requirements.txt file containing pinned dependencies.  I have created source and binary distributions and I am ready to upload them on PyPI.  From a package hosted on PyPI, I would a user to install frozen dependencies via

`pip install <mypackage> -r requirements.txt`

The options for generating a reproducible set of packages is simple in a development environment, but PyPI seems to work differently. I understand PyPI offers source and binary options for installing packages, which by default exclude non-python files from the distribution directories.  I must therefore add the necessary file to the source distribution using `include requirements.txt` in the `MANIFEST.in` file, but I don't know how to add the requirements.txt so that dependencies can be installed from a wheel.

In other words, for packages hosted on PyPI (as both a source distribution and a wheel), how do I make pinned requirements available to get the following commands to work:

```
# Install Pinned Dependencies

pip install <mypackage> --no-wheel -r requirements.txt   # from source

pip install <mypackage> -r requirements.txt              # from wheel (default)
```

Comment: `pip` will install from a `.whl` if one matching your architecture and python version is available. Are the commands listed above failing in some way?

Comment: @memoselyk These `pip` commands work fine in my virutalenv, but I don't know about PyPI.   Reuploading files with the same name is apparently not allowed, so I'm trying to understand its behavior prior.  I've tested the first command locally, but regarding the second, if I upload a wheel, I don't see how PyPI will find the requirements.txt file.

Comment: Are you using a requirements files to state the dependencies of you package, instead of using the `install_requires` keyword? Are you having problems making your `requirements.txt` included in your wheel file?

Comment: @memoselyk I have "unbounded" declarations in my `install_requires` key.  So both options with download the latest dependencies, no problem.  The issue is I must pin them for the current version of my package because a couple dependencies have updated their APIs, and the lastest dependencies break my package. I figure out how to deal with source, but my main problem is including `requirements.txt` in my wheel file.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't bounding the dependencies on the `install_requires`? About the include on wheels have you tried the `data_files` keyword?

Comment: I am unaware of the `data_files` keyword.  I've stayed away from setup keywords in general based on issue people have had with [other keywords](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/).  So you think adding the file to `data_files` is sufficient?

Comment: That keyword is [widely used](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language%3Apython+package_data&type=Code&ref=searchresults), and I have used it successfully myself, so I wouldn't expect any problems with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97445/discussion-between-pylang-and-memoselyk).